# How do I enable support for Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) in OpenSSL on OS X?

Tags: openssl, macos

I want to use the Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) of OpenSSL as documented on https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/cms.html on OS X.

When I try to run `openssl cms` I get the following error:

```
$ openssl cms
openssl:Error: 'cms' is an invalid command.

Standard commands
asn1parse      ca             ciphers        crl            crl2pkcs7
(...)
```

How do I enable support for CMS on OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I can't find this documented anywhere.

The problem here is that the OpenSSL build bundled with OS X doesn't come compiled with CMS supported. In order to enable CMS support you will have to compile your own version of OpenSSL.

First, clone the OpenSSL Github mirror:

```
git clone git@github.com:openssl/openssl.git
```

Checkout a stable version, for example 1.0.2:

```
cd openssl
git checkout OpenSSL_1_0_2
```

Configure the compiled to enable CMS support:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc enable-cms
```

Then make and install openssl:

```
make
make install
```

If everything goes well you should now have your selected version of OpenSSL installed at `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl`. When running `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl cms` you should see the following:

```
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl cms
Usage cms [options] cert.pem ...
where options are
-encrypt       encrypt message
-decrypt       decrypt encrypted message
(...)
```

Note that this will not override your bundled openssl installation, so you will either need to modify your path or use the binary directly.

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer, I was having exactly the same problem and this really helped. I also edited your answer to include the Homebrew alternative.

Comment: FWIW I'm on Sierra and after following the above steps my openssl ended up elsewhere: `/usr/local/bin/openssl cms` worked for me.

Comment: You didn't need to explicitly enable it, it's enabled by default. The key is use to use version 1.0.0 or higher; 0.9.x (which Mac used even after 2010) did not have a cms command, while 1.0.x does (and so does 1.1.x, which was not yet available in 2015). Note however that the smime subcommand in 0.9.x actually implemented both SMIME and CMS _formats_, and still does in 1.0.x and 1.1.x; you don't really need the cms subcommand except for some obscure features in 1.1.x.